# WPF Button Content VerticalAlignment on default button

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I'm not able to center text vertically on a default button (no styles or templates used)

I saw threads like

[Text content in a WPF button not being centred vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839618/text-content-in-a-wpf-button-not-being-centred-vertically)

^^ I'm not setting any text height atleast in button 1.

Not sure what causes this behavior and how to get rid of it efficiently when localisation comes in.

I do get I can set a -ve margin to align text exactly, however that might screw things up for another language. Is this some limitation based on the Default Font Family Expression blend seems to impose?

Any help with this would be great. Seems trivial but cant seem to find a decent explanation for what's causing this behavior.

Xaml code is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="TestButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="ButtonFFAH" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
  <Button Content="ButtonAH" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
                Margin="80,0,0,0" Height="15.627"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>        
</Grid>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I guess the text is well centered vertically with respect to possible accents like for example `Á` or `È`.

Comment: How about if you type "J" or "j" in the Button?

Comment: Don't Button's have a `Padding` property you can use to set the vertical spacing?

Comment: @Rachel They have, but i guess OP is looking for a general solution, that is independent of font and content.

Comment: Hrrmm maybe its just me but I did a quick test and my text is vertically centered. I also have a different button look than these screenshots too (Windows 7). Are you using any custom ControlTemplates or Themes?

Comment: @Clemens I think your answer is what I was looking for. It is internal design as the posted answer suggested and due to the fact that centering is based on all available accents than what the current content is. Seems strange to base the center axis on everything when actual text has none of it. I will accept your answer if you can post that please

Comment: @Rachel I'm on Windows 8 and Expression Blend 5 the beta version that supports WPF 4.5. Font family used by default is Segoe UI. In this question I did not use any templates or styles. Problem does occur the same with or without them and as "icebat" suggested, even with a nested TextBlock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent vertical misalignment is due to the fact that all kinds of accents or other diacritical marks add to the total font height. Although the actual Button content may not contain such characters, the vertical alignment has to take this into account to ensure a common baseline alignment with other Buttons with the same "outer" alignment, for example in the same Grid row.

Answer (score 4):

It`s how it works internally. If you want some more control, just fill button content with more customizable things that just a string. Like this:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
        Margin="80,0,0,0" Height="15.627"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
     <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">ButtonAH</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Cheers for your reply, However this is not the answer for this. You get the same exact behavior using the nested TextBlock element or even with a template using content presenter and nesting that in a stack panel or so. This might be the internal behavior but adding a TextBlock gives no additional control in this regard. You see the same vertical offset with the text now within the TextBlock element when its nested.

Comment: It works for me, but I`m on Windows 7. Maybe that makes the difference, because even button looks are not the same for me (even on classic theme).

Comment: Fixed the issue for me.